# rolling over data-set rows and columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i am using pandas lib to roll over the whole data-set in batches as taking the first 24 rows then make operation and slide down by one row

this is a sample of the data-set :-

[image]

i have manged to start with this code

```
for column in priceDataframe:
    if (priceDataframe[column].notnull()[0:24].sum() == soredVolume[column].notnull()[0:24].sum() and priceDataframe[column].notnull()[0:24].sum() == 24):
        print (True)
    else:
        pass
```

but the batch here is static from `[0:24]` i want to slid over all the data-set i though about : `for loop` than ranges but it's not straight forward as i will have to add 1 to start and 1 to the end of the batch i hope if there is something more simpler than that

i would like out put to be a batches of this huge file as for instance , this is the first batch

[image]

Comment: Did you try with `pandas.DataFrame.rolling`?

Comment: no , i am checking it :)

Comment: `priceDataframe.rolling(24,min_periods=24)` , provide `Rolling [window=24,min_periods=24,center=False,axis=0]` what i am looking for is batches of the dataset

Comment: can you provide a sample of your dataframe and your output? i guess you need `min_periods=1`. Also how many rows does your df have, and what size should the window be?

Comment: And how should the second batch be?

Comment: one step down , i have manged a solution `volumeDataframe[column].loc[index:index+23]`

Comment: Thanks for your help  @joe .